# ACF Relationship Query in the Functions.php to pull into Query ID in Elementor Posts Widget

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to create 'featured posts' in specific category pages. I've set up a relationship ACF and this bit of PHP works fine and produces an array of post IDs.

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$things = get_field("catfeatured", $term);
```

I'm trying to turn this into a query I can stick in the functions.php and then pull into my elementor posts widget using the query ID. I've been messing around for 2 days now but I seem to be no closer. This is the latest of a long line of things that didn't work:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/Cat_Featured', function( $query ) {
    global $post;
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $ids = get_field("catfeatured", $term);
    $query->set( 'post__in', $ids );
});
```

Someone please put me out of my misery.

Comment: Why don't you try using shortcode method?: https://wpcodeus.com/how-to-add-php-code-to-elementor/

Comment: Because I want to use the Posts widget so I need a query ID.

Comment: You can get the query ID in the page and pass it to the function for the shortcode

Comment: How do you mean? Excuse my ignorance. Could you give me an example?

Comment: get the category ID in the category page using $term = get_queried_object(); and then call the function my_elementor_shortcode( $term ); 
Then you can use the $term in the shortcode function in the functions.php file

Comment: OK so I put this in the snippets:
`
<?php
$term = get_queried_object();
// $things = get_field("catfeatured", $term);
?>
`
and the following in the functions.php:

`
add_action( 'elementor/query/Cat_Featured', function( $query, $term ) {
    global $post;
 //$term = get_queried_object();
 $ids = get_field("catfeatured", $term);
    $query->set( 'post__in', $ids );
});
`
But still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

In category page:

```
$term = get_queried_object();                                 
my_elementor_shortcode( $term );
```

Then in functions.php

```
    my_elementor_shortcode( $term ) {
$things = get_field("catfeatured", $term); foreach ($things as $value) { echo "$value <br>"; } add_shortcode( 'my_elementor_php_output', 'my_elementor_shortcode');
```

Then you can use the shortcode [my_elementor_php_output] in the elementor using shortcode widget

Comment: Thanks so much for this but I don't want to use the shortcode in the page to display the results, I want to use the posts widget which means I need a query ID.

Comment: Please check these articles and you can combine these to get your answer:
https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/custom-query-filter/
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172003/how-to-query-posts-by-meta-keys-and-under-specific-category

Comment: Thanks. I've gone through them 100 times over the past 2 days. I have something of a knowledge gap that's infuriating.

Comment: Hope this will answer your question: 
https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/5505

Comment: Thanks for this. It's not a single page, though. It's the category archive that I want to display the featured posts. We seem to be getting further away from an answer :(
In short, I want to create a query that pulls an ACF called 'catfeatured' with the current category and that produces an array of post IDs. I want them passed into the elementor pro posts widget through the 'query id'.